# Identify current/active child routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router

My routes look like this:

```
<Route path="sites/:siteid" component={SiteContainer} >
        <Route path="restore/:version/:action" component={RestoreContainer} />
        <Route path="migrate/:version/:action" component={MigrateContainer} />
</Route>
```

If my current URL is:

```
sites/1/restore/0/list
```

Inside `SiteContainer`'s React component, how can I know which `childRoutes` is getting served currently? As in this example its `childRoutes[0]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured this out. React provides you access to [`children`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.children) props, through:

```
this.props.children
```

Now when I am at URL:

```
sites/1
```

The main route is being accessed, which is loading `SiteContainer`. There is no children, therefore `null`.

When on URL:

```
sites/1/restore/0/list
```

the first child route's component (i.e. RestoreContainer) becomes `children`. Now I can access the route using:

```
this.props.children.props.route
```

To handle both cases, I have following in my `SiteContainer`:

```
childroute = this.props.children && this.props.children.props.route
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`context.router.isActive`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#isactivepathorloc-indexonly) method

#### `isActive(pathOrLoc, indexOnly)`

Returns `true` or `false` depending on if the `pathOrLoc` is active. Will be true for every route in the route branch matched (child route is active, therefore parent is too), unless `indexOnly` is specified, in which case it will only match the exact path.

A route is only considered active if all the URL parameters match, including optional parameters and their presence or absence.

However, only explicitly specified query parameters will be checked. That means that `isActive({ pathname: '/foo', query: { a: 'b' } })` will return `true` when the location is `/foo?a=b&c=d`. To require that a query parameter be absent, specify its value as an explicit `undefined`, e.g. `isActive({ pathname: '/foo', query: { a: 'b', c: undefined } })`, which would be `false` in this example.

Comment: this is not what I am looking for. As stated `isActive` will return true for all childRoutes, unless `indexOnly` specified. But what if I have, say, 10 children routes? In order to check which one is active, using this, one will be required to match against all. This looks ugly. I was hoping if I can get an API that directly points to current active child.